# Activity on comments

Tags: discussion, comments

Many times, when asking for clarification or pointing something out in a commentary, when someone replies without adding the @user it will pass unnoticed.

Is there a way to search for one's own comments which had activity afterwards? (or in a broader sense, questions or answers which have had activity after my last comment).

Comment: When a post you've commented on recieves another comment you get a notification already.  Or at least I always do.

Comment: It totally notified me.  My phone even vibrated.  That's how I responded within 20 seconds

Comment: Both? or just the first one? (the first one should of), this one wouldn't notify either. I didn't get a notification for *your* comment

Comment: @BradleyDotNET If only you and the OP have commented on a post, and the OP comments, you get a notifcation, regardless of the @.  As soon as anyone else has commented, an @ is required to ping anyone but the OP.

Comment: @Servy Ah, I see my understanding of the rule was flawed. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also go to your profile to see your recent comments. Profile > Activity > All Actions > Comments. You can click on the title of the question and the link goes directly to your comment. It's not a search, but you can at least see where you've commented lately.

Comment: @bsmp yes, that's what I do. but It'd be nice to know when there's activity in the questions I commented without scanning them all.

Comment: Perhaps you're attacking this from the wrong angle. You seem to want to be able to go back to questions that you had an interest in; the comment is only an outing of that interest. So favorite the question so you can easily find it back later.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, it's useful to track interesting questions, but I'm not sure if the order in activity tab reflects activity on comments. And I am not going to fav all questions where I drop a comment.

Comment: You're not going to find all questions you drop a comment on either, since as you probably know they're very temporary foot notes that can disappear for any number of reasons and as such make for very unreliable bookmarks. I do get your request though, I usually have two moments in the day where I revisit all my recent comments (to see what's up and to see what can be deleted). It'd be nice to see instantly where there had been activity since my last visit.

Answer (score 15):

You need Data Explorer for this, which of course means you won't get the data until it's loaded in SEDE — which happens once a week, on a weekend. Sample queries:

1. [Posts edited after your comment](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/113603/posts-edited-after-your-comment)
2. [Comments posted after your comment](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/328843/comments-posted-after-your-comment)

I use query #1 to delete my comments that were rendered obsolete by an edit.

Comment: I didn't know it existed, thank you! and almost online : )

Comment: Don't worry, you're gonna be Y2KOK.

Comment: next weekend I'll see your comment.

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing the queries, most useful.